# React: creating a href inside <li>

Tags: reactjs

I have this component:

```
const Candidate = ({candidate}) => {
    return(
        <li href='http://www.google.com' key={candidate.id}>{candidate.first} {candidate.last} ({candidate.company}) </li>
    )
}
```

but it looks like I can't make a `<li>` into a clickable link? I change it to `<a href=''>` and it worked.

What is the best way to go about making this work?

Comment: Put an anchor inside the list element

Comment: that's not a react question, it's basic HTML. href is an attribute that belongs to a "a" tag and can work only with it. if you want a link inside a list element, do <li><a href="...">link here</a></li>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you do `<li><a href=""> </a> </li>`? I would make better since you are making a link. Add the href to the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: yep. the guy below is also correct how you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple anchor tag

```
const Candidate = ({candidate}) => {
    return(
        <li key={candidate.id}>
          <a href='http://www.google.com'>{candidate.first} {candidate.last} ({candidate.company})</a>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Or if you're using react-router have a look at documentation for the Link component: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/custom-link